# How can I have sub-elements of a complex/mixed type with unrestricted order and count?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am working with XML where some elements will contain text with additional markup.  This is similar to this example at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp).  However, I need the markup tags to be able to appear in any order and possibly more than once.

To modify their example for illustration:

```
<letter>
  Dear Mr.<name>John Smith</name>.
  Your order <orderid>1032</orderid>
  will be shipped on <shipdate>2001-07-13</shipdate>.
  Thank you, <name>Bob Adams</name>
</letter>
```

None of the options presented by W3Schools (on the page following the linked example) allow this XML due to the second `<name>` element.  Their explanation of the "indicators" and my testing are consistent.

`<xs:sequence>` - violates the element order

`<xs:choice>` - more than one kind of element is used.

`<xs:all>` - maxOccurs is restricted to "1".

This seems like it should be basic, after all, XHTML allows such things.  How do I define my schema to allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching, I found [this][1] answer, which solved by problem.  @jelovirt upvoted!

Essentially, combining `sequence` and `choice` indicators.

```
<xs:complexType name="textItem" mixed="true">
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="tag_1" type="xs:string" />
    ...
    <xs:element name="tag_n" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: The sequence is unnecessary, just add an unbounded choice directly into textItem.

Comment: Thanks, xcut!

I was still a bit confused as to what was going on.  But I get it now.  I think my previous failed test I had the <choice> nut unbounded, and each element inside unbounded.  So, I had to make the choice once, and could repeat the chosen element, but not mix 'n' match!